# Devstack installation issues with pip version

Tags: python, openstack, devstack

Everytime I try to install devstack I am facing this same error. Can anyone please suggest some possible workarounds for this issue?

```
 ERROR: Links are not allowed as constraints
 +lib/tempest:install_tempest:1             exit_trap
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:491                  local r=1
 ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:492                  jobs -p
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:492                  jobs=
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:495                  [[ -n '' ]]
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:501                  '[' -f '' ']'
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:506                  kill_spinner
 +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:401               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:508                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:509                  echo 'Error on exit'
 Error on exit
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  type -p generate-subunit
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:512                  generate-subunit 1610881819 136 fail
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:514                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
 +./stack.sh:exit_trap:517                  /usr/bin/python3.8 /home/saptarsi/devstack/tools           /worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
```

World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2021-01-17-111235.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:526                  exit 1

[Devstack Install Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq2c1.png)

Comment: Python version? Pip installed? Pip command?

Comment: Python 3.8.5 Pip3 20.0.2

Comment: Searching for the error leads to the bug described at https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1906322. Although the pip version mentioned in the bug is 20.3, I would try an earlier version of Devstack.